# Loading a modal after closing a first (Bootstrap 3)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal on the page (`.lockdown`) that has two close buttons. One of these (`.btn-typoedit`) simply closes the modal, however the other (`.btn-newcontact`) closes the modal and then immediately opens another (`#change-contact`). However, when this second modal closes, the whole page "shifts" slightly and I get space for a second scroll bar appear.

This is the Javascript code I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btn-newcontact').on('click', function() {
        $('#change-contact').modal('show');
    });
});
```

And a JSFddle to see the glitch in action (open the first modal, then click "NEW"): https://jsfiddle.net/z904fzcm/

Looking through the Bootstrap documentation, I can set an event to run on `.hidden.bs.modal`, but I'm not quite sure what's even causing the glitch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watching the way the code changed as modals open/close, I managed to deduce the following:

- As a modal opens, the `body` receives the class `.modal-open` and receives the CSS `padding-right: 17px`.
- When a modal closes, the above class and CSS are removed.
- Because the code to close one modal and open another were within the same `.on('click')` declaration, the `.modal-open` class and CSS were removed but never re-added for the second modal.

In order to combat this I watch for a variable I named `changeContact`, set to `0` on page load, and then I change to `1` when the relevant button is clicked. If that variable is `1` when checking Bootstrap's useful `hidden.bs.modal` event, I **then** open the second modal. This separates the code to two separate functions, meaning the CSS is modified correctly.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var changeContact = 0;

    $('.btn-lockdown').on('click', function() {
        changeContact = 0;
    });

    $('.btn-newcontact').on('click', function() {
        $('.lockdown').modal('hide');
        changeContact = 1;
    });

    $('.lockdown').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
        if (changeContact) {
            $('#change-contact').modal('show');
        }
    });
});
```

[See it in action on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z904fzcm/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Add overflow hidden to the body

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btn-newcontact').on('click', function() {

    $('#change-contact').modal('show');
      $('body').css({'overflow':'hidden'});
    });
});
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/pf9juunm/

a safer solution will be to use a class to toggle the state:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn-newcontact').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#change-contact').addClass('active');
    $('.lockdown').modal('hide');
  });


  $('.lockdown').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    if ($('#change-contact.active').length) $('#change-contact').modal('show');
    $('#change-contact').removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pf9juunm/1/

Comment: Looks quite good - the scrollbar doesn't appear between modals now. I still get the shift in the content though, and the first button on the page stops working?

Comment: That second solution is great - it doesn't move about the page content!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a glitch from Bootstrap modal.

The workarounds can be removing the animation by removing the `fade` or set a timeout (~500ms) before calling `.lockdown`

You could also do this `body { padding-right: 0 !important }`

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/z904fzcm/1/

Comment: You'll notice the scrollbar disappears when the first modal opens, but reappears when the second one does. I wonder if there's a way of stopping that from happening...

Comment: To me it does not appear to me ... it appears to me at the start and when leaving the manners the lateral bar because the text box has a lot of height...

Answer (score 0):

It adds a padding in the body that's why it is shifting slightly.
Try to remove that padding with jQuery.

You can try removeAttr to remove style attribute from body.

```
$('body').removeAttr('style');
```